# I want to write a paper in latex but I don't know how to write in latex

Tags: tutorials

I am a new user of latex tool. Up till now I have  installed WinEdt for that. I want to write my own paper in Latex. Please Give me some suggestions where to start.

Comment: An editing program such as [WinEdt](http://winedt.com/) is a "front end" tool. In case you haven't already done so, you also need to install a TeX distribution -- [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/) and [TeXLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) are both excellent candidates -- to provide the "back end" tools. WinEdt can be configured easily to interact with both TeXLive and MiKTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/15925 and the linked questions.

Comment: I aslo install Bakoma for that purpose.

Answer (score 5):

### Written guides about getting started with `LaTeX`

#### Online ressources

there are a lot of "Getting-started-with-latex" guides and pages in the internet, e. g. you can have a look at http://latex-project.org/guides/ :

In the section "Contributed Documentation" there are 2 pdf guides for beginners:

- http://www.techscribe.co.uk/ta/latex-introduction.pdf and
- http://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf .

#### Good old paper

There are also lots of good books about `LaTeX` for beginners and advanced users and many of them are available in university libraries.
Please have a look at this overview here:

- http://latex-project.org/guides/books.html

### LaTeX courses for beginners

If you are a student, you could also see if your university offers `LaTeX` courses or if you find a more experienced user among your friends/colleagues who can help you.

### LaTeX templates

You say you want to write a paper in LaTeX, so it might be a good idea to see if the publisher of the journal you're targeting already has a LaTeX template which you can use and which already contains the necessary formatting.

### Other ressources

Congratulations! You've found tex.stackexchange, which is an excellent source of information and LaTeX wisdom :-) and already offers a lot answers to the questions which might arise when you start learning and using LaTeX.

Comment: glad I could help you. :-) If you think my answer has answered your question, you can accept it with the green checkmark symbol below the up/downvoting arrows, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow